# Soft conflict between two gradle subprojects in AndroidManifest. How can I mark the conflict and solve it?

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

There are two conflicting subproject dependencies in our build system: PluginGCM and PluginFirebase, and we have a project that needs both.

The only part that is conflicting about them is that both describe a service that listens push notification intents and displays a toast to the user. So when both are present, notification toasts appear doubled.

I'd like to be able to mark the part of the AndroidManifest that conflicts in each subproject, and select just one of them during merge.

Is this possible? If not, how can I solve this conflict?

Comment: If by "select one of them", you mean "disable one of them", use `android:enabled` on the `<service>` element, tied to a [manifest placeholder](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support), where your `build.gradle` file indicates whether or not that service is desired for this particular build.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be on the right path, but I have 3 build.gradle files, not just one.

(edit: just learned that enter submits the comment, instead of just making a new line..)

The docs aren't very clear about what happens when you define the same placeholder with different values in multiple subprojects.